# 2 prometheus query on one grafana time series

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Hye I want to compare direct database execution time with an API call execution time and visualize 2 lines on the same graph, I added metrics collectors and collected all the required metrics and I have 2 queries like this:

```
sum(rate(query_duration_milliseconds_sum{query_name="getPrintProviderStats"}[1h])) by (query_name)  / sum(rate(query_duration_milliseconds_sum{query_name="someQuery"}[1h]))  by (query_name)
```

and

```
sum(rate(request_duration_milliseconds_sum{uri="/api/v1/print-provider-stats"}[1h])) by (uri)  / sum(rate(request_duration_milliseconds_sum{uri="some/url"}[1h]))  by (uri)
```

I added both queries to the Grafana time series, but the visualization is incorrect [image] and [image]

As you can see smaller value for some reason visualized as a bigger one

Comment: Hmm. Looks like a bug in legend visualisation. Consider filling issue in Grafana's repo.